# How can I put frames in textviews to have the form of a table?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

[IMAGE-Something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrQ2D.jpg) 
I have begun to create an application that will show us the weather conditions of some cities.My problem is that I do not know how can I put frames in textviews to have the form of a table.If there are any solutions please help me.

**My xml code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.junior_marg.current_weather.Main12Activity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/c"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview12"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="92dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/d"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview12"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview14"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview13"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/h2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview14"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview17"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview16"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="77dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview18"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/i2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview16"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview19"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview18"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="130dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview20"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/j2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview18"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview21"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview20"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview19"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="104dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview22"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/k2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview20"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview23"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview22"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview21"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview24"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/l2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview22"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview25"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview24"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview23"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="94dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview26"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/m2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview24"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview27"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview26"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview25"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview28"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/n2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview26"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview29"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview28"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview27"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview30"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/o2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview28"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview31"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview30"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview29"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview32"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/p2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview30"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview33"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview32"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview31"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="73dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview34"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/q2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview32"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview35"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview34"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview33"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview36"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/r2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview34"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview37"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview36"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview35"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview38"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/s2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview36"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview39"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview38"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview37"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview40"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/t2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview38"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview41"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview40"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview39"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="122dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview42"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/u2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview40"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview43"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview42"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview41"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="151dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

**My java code**

```
TextView mTextView;
TextView mTextView2;
TextView mTextView3;
TextView mTextView4;
TextView mTextView5;
TextView mTextView6;
TextView mTextView7;
TextView mTextView8;
TextView mTextView9;
TextView mTextView10;
TextView mTextView11;
TextView mTextView12;
TextView mTextView13;
TextView mTextView14;
TextView mTextView15;
TextView mTextView16;

String therm;
String ygrasia;
String simdrosou;
String anemos;
String varom;
String simerinosy;
String ragd;
String trexkak;
String miniaiosy;
String ethsiosy;
String aisthpsix;
String yperithriakt;
String deiktisdis;
String hliakiakt;
String anatoli;
String disi;

String url;
Document doc;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main12);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview13);
    mTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview15);
    mTextView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview17);
    mTextView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview19);
    mTextView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview21);
    mTextView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview23);
    mTextView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview25);
    mTextView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview27);
    mTextView9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview29);
    mTextView10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview31);
    mTextView11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview33);
    mTextView12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview35);
    mTextView13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview37);
    mTextView14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview39);
    mTextView15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview41);
    mTextView16 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview43);

    url = "http://penteli.meteo.gr/stations/trikala/";

    doc = null;

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Element table = doc.select("table").get(0);
    Elements rows = table.select("tr");

    Element row = rows.get(5);
    Elements cols = row.select("td");

    therm =  cols.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView.setText(therm);

    Element row_2 = rows.get(6);
    Elements cols_2 = row_2.select("td");

    ygrasia =  cols_2.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView2.setText(ygrasia);

    Element row_3 = rows.get(7);
    Elements cols_3 = row_3.select("td");

    simdrosou =  cols_3.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView3.setText(simdrosou);

    Element row_4 = rows.get(8);
    Elements cols_4 = row_4.select("td");

    anemos =  cols_4.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView4.setText(anemos);

    Element row_5 = rows.get(9);
    Elements cols_5 = row_5.select("td");

    varom =  cols_5.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView5.setText(varom);

    Element row_6 = rows.get(10);
    Elements cols_6 = row_6.select("td");

    simerinosy =  cols_6.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView6.setText(simerinosy);

    Element row_7 = rows.get(11);
    Elements cols_7 = row_7.select("td");

    ragd =  cols_7.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView7.setText(ragd);

    Element row_8 = rows.get(12);
    Elements cols_8 = row_8.select("td");

    trexkak =  cols_8.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView8.setText(trexkak);

    Element row_9 = rows.get(13);
    Elements cols_9 = row_9.select("td");

    miniaiosy =  cols_9.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView9.setText(miniaiosy);

    Element row_10 = rows.get(14);
    Elements cols_10 = row_10.select("td");

    ethsiosy =  cols_10.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView10.setText(ethsiosy);

    Element row_11 = rows.get(15);
    Elements cols_11 = row_11.select("td");

    aisthpsix =  cols_11.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView11.setText(aisthpsix);

    Element row_12 = rows.get(16);
    Elements cols_12 = row_12.select("td");

    yperithriakt =  cols_12.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView12.setText(yperithriakt);

    Element row_13 = rows.get(17);
    Elements cols_13 = row_13.select("td");

    deiktisdis =  cols_13.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView13.setText(deiktisdis);

    Element row_14 = rows.get(18);
    Elements cols_14 = row_14.select("td");

    hliakiakt =  cols_14.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView14.setText(hliakiakt);

    Element row_15 = rows.get(19);
    Elements cols_15 = row_15.select("td");

    anatoli =  cols_15.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView15.setText(anatoli);

    Element row_16 = rows.get(20);
    Elements cols_16 = row_16.select("td");

    disi =  cols_16.get(1).text() ;

    mTextView16.setText(disi);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a UI mockup/design you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes of course,but I'm new on the page.How can i sent you a photo of this?

Comment: There should be attach button outside the text box. Try drag and drop.

Comment: I've already uploaded the photo.

Comment: If there are any solutions please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get something that resembles a table, I suggest using a [TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Alternatively, you might try the new [FlexboxLayout.](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)